# Python type hinting, output type depends on input type

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

Consider the following function

```py
import typing
def make_list(el : typing.Any):
    return [el, el]
```

How do I hint that it returns

```py
typing.List[type(el)]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's what [`TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics) is for:

```
from typing import TypeVar, List

T = TypeVar('T')

def make_list(el: T) -> List[T]:
    return [el, el]
```